# Django centos server not receiving requests

Tags: python, django, centos

I just deployed my Django project to a local CentOS server for testing. The problem  is that after I run my server like: 192.168.1.4 (server ip), and run in port:3001 and then I send a request from another computer on the same LAN this requests are not being received by the server.

Local request from the server to the server are working fine.

Also:

```
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
   CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
   CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Django: 2.1
CentOs: 7

The command netstat shows that indeed the port is listening.
The port has already been opened in the router.

Comment: Are you using some service? i.e nginx, or some Apache service (tomcat or some other) ?

Comment: Yes, I am using xaamp

Comment: Xampp*, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when netstat showed that the port was open, it was closed in the server. I managed t open it with the following command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3001/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd –reload
```

I hope this helps anyone else having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network.

To access your machine from other machines on the network, use its own IP address 192.168.1.4 or 0.0.0.0.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: I understand, perhaps I was not clear in my post, the command I use is: python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.4:3001, hence running its own IP